# Two DataTable into one DataGrid -WPF

Tags: wpf, datatable

I have dwo DataTable's and one DataGrid, and I want to merge trzis DataTable to one into DataGrid.
I do this:

```
 DataTable DT = n.Tables[1];
                DataTable DT2 = n.Tables[0];
                DT.Merge(DT2);

                dataGrid1.ItemsSource = DT.DefaultView;
```

"n" is a DataSet.
Its all fine, I got the merge two table to one. But it look's like:

[image]

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/FileUpload/-1776981690/Budget.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have to run a sql query (or LINQ 2 SQL query) on these two tables that matches rows based on a foreign key i.e. in your DT1 and DT2 there has to be some column that carries same value so that you can match the two and create a single tuple having columns from both tables...  set the output of the (SQl \ LINQ) query to the itemsource of the datagrid.